# grails acess array data

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have problem with saving data to my cassandra database,
I'm getting this error 
and there is my code:

```
class User {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    List books
    static hasMany = [books:Book]

}
```

---

```
class Book {
        String title
        static belongsTo = [author : User]
}
```

---

```
class BootStrap {

        def init = { servletContext ->
            def user01= new User(firstName: "Abderrahime",lastName: "FARHANE")
            def book = new Book(title: "test")
            def book2 = new Book(title: "test2")

            user01.addToBooks(book)
            user01.addToBooks(book2)
            user01.save(flush: true)


            def user02= User.findById(user01.id)
            println(user02.books)
        }
        def destroy = {
        }
 }
```

---

```
| Running application...
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at
```

Comment: Hmm... that stack trace reveals a symptom, but not the cause. Look deeper. You can also try saving like this to make sure it's not failing validation: `user01.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)`.

Comment: Where is the full stacktrace? get it by adding --stacktrace to grails run-app

Answer (score -1):

Remove `List books` from `User` class. You have already declared that there is a collection of books by `static hasMany = [books:Book]`

Comment: If he wants it bidirectional, he doesn't have to change anything in domain classes.

Comment: So you are saying declaring the same class property twice, will make it bidirectional? Interesting! Why would it make it bidirectional?

Comment: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#ormdsl read section **6.3.3 Understanding Cascading Updates and Deletes**

Comment: Oh, wait - now I see it. There is unnecessary `List books` in domain class User! I thought all the time that you're talking about bidirectional relations!

Answer (score -1):

I'm almost sure you didn't publish full stacktrace.

But let's check your code step by step and repair it:

```
    def init = { servletContext ->
        def user01= new User(firstName: "Abderrahime",lastName: "FARHANE")

        def book = new Book(title: "test")
        def book2 = new Book(title: "test2")
        //if you want to add any of these books to user01, 
        //you should first persist (save) books in database

        //but you should remember also that 
        //each instance of Book belongs to specified User
        //so author of Book can not be null
        //so first you need to save your user
        user01.save(flush: true)

        //then save your books
        book.author = user01
        book.save(flush: true)

        book2.author = user01
        book2.save(flush: true)

        //then add them (books) to user:
        user01.addToBooks(book)
        user01.addToBooks(book2)
        user01.save(flush: true)

        //now it should work:
        def user02= User.findById(user01.id)
        println(user02.books)
    }
```

Comment: That's not resolve my problem when I use hibernate it's work, but whit Cassandra database, it's doesn't work so I use ListString> book and I put the ids of books and use UUID and put the id of the user 
It's seems that Cassandra doesn't support relation like hasMany and belongsTo